# Objective -C, How to clear shared Instance all data at once?

Tags: objective-c, singleton, sharedpreferences

I am using shared instance class for saving basic user's information like user_id, age, name and many more. Now I need to remove all data at once during logout. I do not want to delete data one by one. Is there any way by which we can do this? Any suggestion will be Great!! Thanks in advance.

What I have done till now, But it is not working. I have also tried some other ways whichever I found on on Internet, but did not work :

```
static GlobalValues *sharedManager = nil;

+(GlobalValues*)sharedManager{
//static id sharedManager;
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    sharedManager = [[GlobalValues alloc] init];
});
return sharedManager;
}

+(void)resetSharedInstance {
@synchronized(self) {
    sharedManager = nil;
}
}
```

Comment: Shared instances should not be re-allocated during the lifespan of an app.  Once created, the sharedInstance should stick around forever.   So, really, this is just a matter of implementing a `reset` method on the shared instance that resets the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this strategy , it's about to clear properties of the object not the object itself and reset them again as you like

.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
 @interface DataClass : NSObject


  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray*moreNames;



  +(DataClass*)getInstance;

  @end
```

.m

```
#import "DataClass.h"

@implementation DataClass

static DataClass *instance = nil;

+(DataClass *)getInstance
{
   @synchronized(self)
{
    if(instance==nil)
    {
        instance= [DataClass new];

        instance.moreNames=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"moreName1", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName2", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName3", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName4", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName5", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName6", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName7", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"moreName8", nil),nil];


    }
}
return instance;
}

 -(void)clearContents
 {

    self.moreNames = nil

 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign nil to static varible. The problem here is that the init block which is assigned to dispatch_once will not be called the second time, so that you can not init the shareinstance again.

I agree with @Sh_Khan`s strategy. According to what you want I guess, I think you could put all your data in a model (user_id, age, name...), then reset the model when loging out:

```
+ (DataManager *)shareInstance {

    //static id sharedManager;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedManager = [[DataManager alloc] init];
        sharedManager.model = [Model new];
    });

    return sharedManager;

}

+ (void)resetSharedInstance {

    @synchronized(self) {
        sharedManager.model = [Model new]; 
    }

}
```